# Генерация лабиринта

Tags: java, массивы

Требуется написать алгоритм генерации лабиринта размером 10x10 и реализовать интерфейс прохождения кратчайшего пути между двумя точками.
Обозначения:
"# - стена
. - дорога
@ - начало маршрута
X - конец маршрута"

```
public interface Navigator {

char[][] searchRoute(char[][] map);
}
```

Если маршрут проложить невозможно, метод searchRoute должен возвращать null.
Пример:
ввод:

```
...@.     или    ..X..
.####            #####
.....            .....
####.            .@...
.X...            .....
```

вывод:

```
+++@.     или     null
+####
+++++
####+
.X+++
```

Понимаю, что тема не новая, но подходящих решений в интернете я так и не нашел.
Сложные алгоритмы генерации лабиринтов не совсем подходят, т.к. они предполагают обязательное наличие выхода из лабиринта. Мне же нужно заполнить поле 10x10 двумя символами в рандомном порядке и уже в полученном поле искать маршрут между двумя точками. А дальше чем заполнение массива только одним символом я продвинуться не могу.

Comment: Если не нашли решения - напишите своё. Сдаётся мне, в этом и есть суть этой (учебной?) задачи: не найти в интернете, а придумать и реализовать своё решение.

Comment: [Генерация лабиринтов](http://algolist.manual.ru/games/maze.php) и [волновой алгоритм](http://algolist.manual.ru/games/wavealg.php). Может поможет

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь алгоритмом [A*](https://habrahabr.ru/post/331192/) для поиска пути. И генерации лабиринта.

Суть простая. Заполняете поле случайными "весами". По алгоритму, ищете 2-3 оптимальных пути. Их делаете неприкасаемыми, а остальное поле заполняете как угодно. Но правда маршрут всегда можно будет проложить.

Comment: Благодарю за советы в комментариях и ответ. Но они мне не помогли. У меня не получается заменить один символ другим в рандомном порядке во всем массиве.